# HTML5 Canvas - Rotate by anchor using a mouse

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am developing in  html5's canvas element. I have the follwing code and it is draggable and resizable image. How can I turn it to rotatable by a anchor too? How can I provide live rotating by an anchor. I saw other codes samples, but do not know how to implement it.
Sampler  Working:
http://jsfiddle.net/LAS8L/588/

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var isDown = false;


var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
var resizerRadius = 8;
var rr = resizerRadius * resizerRadius;
var draggingResizer = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
var imageX = 50;
var imageY = 50;
var imageWidth, imageHeight, imageRight, imageBottom;
var draggingImage = false;
var startX;
var startY;

var cx = canvas.width / 2;
var cy = canvas.height / 2;

var w;
var h;
var r = 0;



var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    imageWidth = img.width;
    imageHeight = img.height;
    imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
    imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight
    draw(true, false);
}
img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/facesSmall.png";


function draw(withAnchors, withBorders) {

    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw the image
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);

    // optionally draw the draggable anchors
    if (withAnchors) {
        drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageY);
        drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageY);
        drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageBottom);
        drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageBottom);
    }

    // optionally draw the connecting anchor lines
    if (withBorders) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(imageX, imageY);
        ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageY);
        ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageBottom);
        ctx.lineTo(imageX, imageBottom);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}

function drawDragAnchor(x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, resizerRadius, 0, pi2, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function anchorHitTest(x, y) {

    var dx, dy;

    // top-left
    dx = x - imageX;
    dy = y - imageY;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (0);
    }
    // top-right
    dx = x - imageRight;
    dy = y - imageY;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (1);
    }
    // bottom-right
    dx = x - imageRight;
    dy = y - imageBottom;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (2);
    }
    // bottom-left
    dx = x - imageX;
    dy = y - imageBottom;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (3);
    }
    return (-1);

}





function desenhe() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawRotationHandle(true);
    drawRect();
}


function drawRect() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    ctx.rotate(r);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, -imageWidth, -imageheight, w, h);
    //    ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
    //    ctx.fillRect(-w/2,-h/2,w,h);
    ctx.restore();
}


function drawRotationHandle(withFill) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    ctx.rotate(r);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, -1);
    ctx.lineTo(imageWidth + 20, -1);
    ctx.lineTo(imageWidth + 20, -7);
    ctx.lineTo(imageWidth + 30, -7);
    ctx.lineTo(imageWidth + 30, 7);
    ctx.lineTo(imageWidth + 20, 7);
    ctx.lineTo(imageWidth + 20, 1);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 1);
    ctx.closePath();
    if (withFill) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fill();
    }
    ctx.restore();
}




function hitImage(x, y) {
    return (x > imageX && x < imageX + imageWidth && y > imageY && y < imageY + imageHeight);
}


function handleMouseDown(e) {
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    draggingResizer = anchorHitTest(startX, startY);
    draggingImage = draggingResizer < 0 && hitImage(startX, startY);
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    draggingResizer = -1;
    draggingImage = false;
    draw(true, false);
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {

    if (draggingResizer > -1) {

        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        // resize the image
        switch (draggingResizer) {
            case 0:
                //top-left
                imageX = mouseX;
                imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                imageY = mouseY;
                imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                break;
            case 1:
                //top-right
                imageY = mouseY;
                imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                break;
            case 2:
                //bottom-right
                imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                break;
            case 3:
                //bottom-left
                imageX = mouseX;
                imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                break;
        }

        if(imageWidth<25){imageWidth=25;}
        if(imageHeight<25){imageHeight=25;}

        // set the image right and bottom
        imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
        imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight;

        // redraw the image with resizing anchors
        draw(true, true);

    } else if (draggingImage) {

        imageClick = false;

        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
        var dx = mouseX - startX;
        var dy = mouseY - startY;
        imageX += dx;
        imageY += dy;
        imageRight += dx;
        imageBottom += dy;
        // reset the startXY for next time
        startX = mouseX;
        startY = mouseY;

        // redraw the image with border
        draw(false, true);

    }


}


$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

I would like to work this way: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/QqwKR/ but I don't know how merge the code. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hey @markE can you help me?

Comment: This sounds like a solid case of "you need to do more research". You clearly have some coding ability, so find a few tutorials that cover how rotations around an arbitrary coordinate work, maybe even specific to javascript (Although maths is universal, what works in C++ or python works in JavaScript, too), and then apply that new knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function the will set the transform to scale rotate and translate an rectangle or anything.

```
function setTransform(ctx,x,y,scale,rotate){
    var xdx = Math.cos(rotate) * scale;  // create the x axis
    var xdy = Math.sin(rotate) * scale;
    ctx.setTransform(xdx, xdy, - xdy, xdx, x, y);
}
```

The canvas transform is set after that. Now just draw the object in its local space coords.

Eg draw at center of canvas double scale and 45deg rotation

```
setTransform(ctx,canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2,2,Math.PI /4);
ctx.strokeRect(-100,-100,200,200);
```

You will notice that the coordinates are negative. This is because I want the center of the box to be at the center of the canvas. If I wanted the top left of the box to be at the center

```
ctx.strokeRect(0,0,200,200);
```

or the bottom right

```
ctx.strokeRect(-200,-200,200,200);
```

Back to the centered box I can move it anywhere

```
setTransform(
    ctx,
    Math.random() * canvas.width, // random x pos
    Math.random() * canvas.height, // random y pos
    Math.random() * 10 + 0.1,   // random scale
    Math.random() * Math.PI * 2 // random rotation
);
```

The transform is random but I do not need to care I can still draw the box in local coordinates.

```
ctx.strokeRect(-100,-100,200,200);
```

And it will be draw where ever the transform has set it to.

Using `ctx.setTransform` saves the hassle of using save and restore.

If at any stage you need to return to the default transform

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

The problem you will next face is that the mouse coordinates are in canvas coordinates while the object is in its local space. You need to convert the mouse coordinates into the local object coordinates.

This is done by multiplying the mouse coordinates by the inverse of the matrix. A bit of maths here.

```
function getMouseLocal(mousex,mouseY,x,y,scale,rot){
    var xdx = Math.cos(rotate) * scale; // create the x axis
    var xdy = Math.sin(rotate) * scale;

    // get the cross product of the two axies     
    var cross = xdx * xdx - xdy * -xdy;
    // or
    var cross = Math.pow(xdx,2) + Math.pow(xdy,2);

    // then create the inverted axies 
    var ixdx = xdx / cross;   // create inverted x axis
    var ixdy = -xdy / cross;
    var iydx = xdy / cross;   // create inverted y axis
    var iydy = xdx / cross;

    // now remove the origin from the mouse coords
    mouseX -= x;
    mouseY -= y;

    // multiply by the invers matrix    
    var localMouseX = mouseX * ixdx + mouseY * iydx;
    var localMouseY = mouseX * ixdy + mouseY * iydy;

    // and return the result
    return {x : localMouseX, y : localMouseY};
}
```

Now you have the mouse coordinates in the local space. If you need to find out if the mouse is inside the box you

```
setTransform(ctx,100,100,2,Math.PI/4);
ctx.strokeRect(-100,-100,200,200);
var localMouse= getMouseLocal(mouseX,mouseY,100,100,2,Math.PI/4);
if(localMouse.x > -100 && localMouse.x < -100 + 200 && localMouse.y > -100 && localMouse.y < -100 + 200){
    // mouse is inside the box
}
```

That should give you what you need.

**UPDATE**

I forgot you  want to scale both x and y.. So below are the modified functions for scaling both X and Y axies

```
// sx and sy are scale x and y
function setTransform(ctx,x,y,sx,sy,rotate){
    var xdx = Math.cos(rotate);  // create the x axis
    var xdy = Math.sin(rotate);
    ctx.setTransform(xdx * sx, xdy * sx, - xdy * sy, xdx * sy, x, y);
}
```

And getting the mouse to local

```
function getMouseLocal(mousex,mouseY,x,y,sx,sy,rot){
    var xdx = Math.cos(rotate); // create the x axis
    var xdy = Math.sin(rotate);

    // get the cross product of the two axies     
    var cross = xdx * sx * xdx * sy - xdy *sx * -xdy * sy;
    // or
    // this shortcut does not work now.
    // var cross = Math.pow(xdx,2) + Math.pow(xdy,2);

    // then create the inverted axies 
    var ixdx = (xdx * sy) / cross;   // create inverted x axis
    var ixdy = (-xdy * sx) / cross;
    var iydx = (xdy * sy) / cross;   // create inverted y axis
    var iydy = (xdx * sx) / cross;

    // now remove the origin from the mouse coords
    mouseX -= x;
    mouseY -= y;

    // multiply by the invers matrix    
    var localMouseX = mouseX * ixdx + mouseY * iydx;
    var localMouseY = mouseX * ixdy + mouseY * iydy;

    // and return the result
    return {x : localMouseX, y : localMouseY};
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Blindman67, the problem is that i´m a begginer on html5 canvas. And I dont know how put this code that you wrote with the code that i already have. Merge. Can you write your code with my code together please?

Comment: @MarcelBomfim I will have a look when I return to the computer, but that will not be until tomorrow.

Comment: oh ! No problem! @ Blindman67, i can wait quite happy , I spent a long time today in front of computer trying to solve this problem . Thank you very much! I'll be waiting.

Comment: @MarcelBomfim Having had another look at your code it seems to me to be all copy and past. We are not here as a free code writing service but rather to provide a resource from which to learn. Sorry but it would not be in the spirit of SO to write your code for you. I suggest you tackle the problem and ask more specific questions as you come across difficulties.

Comment: what are sx and sy? could you explain the parameters for this signature? `getMouseLocal(mousex,mouseY,x,y,sx,sy,rot)`

Comment: @iwrestledabearonce they are scale X axis `sx` and scale Y axis `sy`